# C error: "conflicting types for"

Tags: c, types

My program includes the following code:

```
static short index(key)
 unsigned char *key;
{
    long i, sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; key[i]; i++)
        sum += key[i];
    return(sum % TABLE_SIZE);
}
```

But, it gives following error:

```
table.c:46:14: error: conflicting types for 'index'
 static short index(key)
              ^
```

I'm a C newbie, read about prototyping etc., but I cannot solve the problem.

Comment: a) Why you´re using this old parameter syntax? b) What´s line 46?

Comment: He's probably using an old book.

Comment: You have an old-style (obsolete) function definition. The modern equivalent, since 1989, is `static short index(unsigned char *key) { /* ... */ }` -- except that, as merlin2011's answer says, you should pick a name other than `index`. There is no good reason to use old-style function declarations or definitions; always use prototypes.

Comment: The error message I get says "warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘index’". Did your error message include the word "built-in"? What compiler are you using? If it's gcc, what version (`gcc --version`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`index` is a function in the `C` library. If you choose a different name for your function, that error will go away.

From the [man](http://linux.die.net/man/3/index) page, we see that it takes a `const char*` and an `int`.

```
 #include <strings.h>

 char *index(const char *s, int c);
```

Comment: The `<strings.h>` header and the `index` function are both non-standard and obsolete. The standard replacement is `strchr()` declared in `<string.h>`. Calling your own function`index` shouldn't cause a problem unless you have a `#include <strings.h>`, which you probably shouldn't have anyway.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I have a modern `gcc` and I still a conflict without the `#include`. I believe that the error is happening at link time.

Comment: I just tried it, and I do get an error (from the compiler, not from the linker): `c.c:3: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘index’`. gcc recognizes it at treats it specially even though it's non-standard (because gcc itself is non-standard by default). The diagnostic goes away if I compile with `gcc -std=...`. Still, even though `index()` is obsolete and non-standard, it's a good idea to avoid using the name. You might update your answer to mention this.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I changed name of the 'index' function, and no more errors.